# Powerpoint Online Office365 Content add-in never loads in "Slide Show" mode, Office.EventType.ActiveViewChanged is never fired

Tags: office-js

I've created a "Content Add-In" that I'm sideloading into Office365's powerpoint online.

- The Content add-in shows properly when the powerpoint presentation is in
  "edit" mode.
- I am able to use the code found in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/powerpoint-add-ins) to
  determine the current view mode and register an
  Office.EventType.ActiveViewChanged event.

[image]

My issue is switching to "Slide Show" mode.  The Add-In does not show and no requests are even attempted to be made to my machine?

[image]

Can anyone provide any insights?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this issue by creating a very basic content add-in (as described in the [PowerPoint quick start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/powerpoint-add-ins-get-started?tabs=visual-studio)), that doesn't contain any logic related to 'active view'. This seems to suggest a problem with the way content add-ins run in presentation mode within PowerPoint Online, rather than the issue being related to / caused by your logic related to 'active view'.

Comment: I've opened an issue **OfficeDev/office-js** GitHub repo for the product team to investigate: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/302. Please subscribe to notifications on that issue if you'd like to be notified when the product team responds and/or asks for any additional information. Thanks!